# OpenGL fragment shader outputs no color when attempting to access first item in an array

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I am working on learning some more advanced concepts in OpenGL. I am trying to implement cube mapped omni-directional shadows, but have had no success yet. All I know is that if I attempt to use the cube mapped data that the fragment shader no longer produces any color at all. I assume that the fragment shader is crashing because if I comment out the code for spot/point lights then I get color. I narrowed it down to my new CalcOmniShadowFactor function by commenting/uncommenting code. When it attempts to read from a uniform array of structs, I get no color. If I manually have the same function return any float, I still get at least SOME color because ambient light is not being affected by shadows.

I have combed over my code with little success. I have put breakpoints in the C++ code to ensure that the correct data was being sent to the GPU. As far as I know, it is, but the cube shader program does create much of the data on its own. Without some sort of GPU debugger, I am having difficulty figuring out where the problem originates.

Here is the code for the fragment shader I am using:

```c
#version 330

// As a reminder, these are all in world space except fragDirectionalLightSpacePos
in vec3 fragPos;
in vec2 fragTex;
in vec3 fragNormal;
in vec4 fragDirectionalLightSpacePos;

out vec4 color;

// Should be the same as the same constant in Constants.h
// TODO: pass this in from the c++ code so we don't have to sync them.
const int MAX_LIGHTS = 16;

struct Light
{
    vec3 color;
    float ambientIntensity;
    float diffuseIntensity;
};

struct DirectionalLight
{
    Light base;
    vec3 direction;
};

struct PointLight 
{
    Light base;
    vec3 position;
    float constantIntensity;
    float linearIntensity;
    float quadIntensity;
};

struct SpotLight
{
    PointLight base;
    vec3 direction;
    float maxAngleCos;
};

struct Material
{
    float specularIntensity;
    float shininess;
};

struct OmniShadowMap
{
    samplerCube shadowMap;
    float farPlane;
};

uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

// I don't manually set this in the CPP code because the default value is 0, which is what I want
// TODO: manually set this where appropriate.
uniform sampler2D texSampler;
uniform sampler2D directionalShadowMapSampler;
uniform Material material;

uniform int pointLightCount;
uniform int spotLightCount;

uniform DirectionalLight directionalLight;
uniform PointLight pointLights[MAX_LIGHTS];
uniform SpotLight spotLights[MAX_LIGHTS];

// An omni shadow map must be created for each spot light and each point light
uniform OmniShadowMap omniShadowMaps[MAX_LIGHTS + MAX_LIGHTS];

vec3 omniShadowOffsetDirs[20] = vec3[]
(
    vec3(1, 1, 1), vec3(1, -1, 1), vec3(-1, -1, 1), vec3(-1, 1, 1),
    vec3(1, 1, -1), vec3(1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, -1, -1), vec3(-1, 1, -1),
    vec3(1, 1, 0), vec3(1, -1, 0), vec3(-1, -1, 0), vec3(-1, 1, 0),
    vec3(1, 0, 1), vec3(-1, 0, 1), vec3(1, 0, -1), vec3(-1, 0, -1),
    vec3(0, 1, 1), vec3(0, -1, 1), vec3(0, -1, -1), vec3(0, 1, -1)
);

float CalcDirectionalShadowFactor(DirectionalLight light)
{
    vec3 projectionCoords = fragDirectionalLightSpacePos.xyz / fragDirectionalLightSpacePos.w;
    // Need to convert normalized space coords which range from -1 to 1 to texture 
    // coords which range from 0 to 1
    projectionCoords = (projectionCoords * 0.5) + 0.5;

    float currentDepth = projectionCoords.z;

    vec3 shadowNormal = normalize(fragNormal);
    vec3 lightDir = normalize(light.direction);

    // Making a bias based on the angle between the light and the normal will produce
    // more consistent results.
    float bias = max(0.005 * (1.0 - dot(shadowNormal, lightDir)), 0.0005);

    float shadow = 0.0;
    vec2 texelSize = 1.0 / textureSize(directionalShadowMapSampler, 0);

    for (int i = -1; i < 2; i ++)
    {
        for (int j = -1; j < 2; j ++)
        {
            // You get the .r component of the texture because the first component of any texture sampler is R from RGB
            // In this case that is the only component of the texture.
            float percentageCloserFilteringDepth = texture(directionalShadowMapSampler, projectionCoords.xy + texelSize * vec2(i, j)).r;
            shadow += currentDepth - bias > percentageCloserFilteringDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        }
    }
    
    // divide the shadow value by the number of texels I tested. In this case 9.
    shadow /= 9;

    // If the projection coordinates are beyond the edge of the texture then set the shadow to 0
    if (projectionCoords.z > 1.0)
    {
        shadow = 0.0;
    }

    return shadow;
}

float CalcOmniShadowFactor(PointLight light, int shadowIndex)
{
    vec3 fragToLight = fragPos - light.position;
    float current = length(fragToLight);
        
    float shadow = 0.0;
    float bias = 0.15;
    int numSamples = 20;
    
    float viewDistance = length(cameraPosition - fragPos);
    // This is rather clever. The closer something is to the camera, the more blurred the edges of the shadows become.
    // If you set the sampling distance to high, it may look fine up close, but when you zoom out, the shadow edges look
    // too big. If you set the sampling distance too low then they look great from a distance, but look too sharp up close
    // This will adjust the blur based on distance so it always looks good.

    // **************************************
    // STACKOVERFLOW - When I try to access omniShadowMaps[0], my fragment shader stops working entirely.
    // If I comment the foobar line out, then I get color again.
    // **************************************
    float foobar = omniShadowMaps[0].farPlane;

    return 0.0;

    //float diskRadius = (1.0 + (viewDistance/omniShadowMaps[shadowIndex].farPlane)) / 25.0;
    //
    //for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i ++)
    //{
    //  float closest = texture(omniShadowMaps[shadowIndex].shadowMap, fragToLight + diskRadius * omniShadowOffsetDirs[i]).r;
    //  closest *= omniShadowMaps[shadowIndex].farPlane;
    //
    //  shadow += current - bias > closest ? 1.0 : 0.0; 
    //}
    //
    //shadow /= float(numSamples);
    //
    //return shadow;
}

vec4 CalcLightByDirection(Light light, vec3 lightDirection, float shadowFactor)
{
    vec3 fragNormalizedNormal = normalize(fragNormal);
    vec3 fragCameraDir = normalize(cameraPosition - fragPos);
    vec3 fragToLight = normalize(-lightDirection);

    vec4 ambientColor = vec4(light.color, 1.0f) * light.ambientIntensity;

    // dotNormalLight determines how much the diffuse light affects the fragment.
    // If the angle between the light and the normal is less than 90 degs, then I want the cosine of the
    // angle between them, which we find with the dot product. If the angle is greater than 90 degs, then
    // the light is behind the face, so I want dotNormalLight to be zero, not negative (there is no
    // such thing as negative light values in my world.)
    float dotNormalLight = max(dot(fragNormalizedNormal, fragToLight), 0.0f);
    vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(light.color, 1.0f) * light.diffuseIntensity * dotNormalLight;

    vec4 specularColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // Specular is 0 if the light is behind the face.
    if (dotNormalLight > 0.0f)
    {
        // Blinn-Phong shading uses a vector they call H which is halfway between
        // Eye vector and the normal vector. I don't know of a better name for this.
        vec3 halfVector = normalize(fragCameraDir + fragToLight);

        // blinn = (normal.half)^shininess
        specularColor = pow(max(dot(fragNormalizedNormal, halfVector), 0.0f), material.shininess) * material.specularIntensity * vec4(light.color, 1.0f);
    }

    return ambientColor + ((diffuseColor + specularColor) * (1.0 - shadowFactor));
}

vec4 CalcPointLight(PointLight pointLight, int shadowIndex)
{   
    vec3 lightDirection = fragPos - pointLight.position;
    float distance = length(lightDirection);
    lightDirection = normalize(lightDirection);

    float shadowFactor = CalcOmniShadowFactor(pointLight, shadowIndex); 

    vec4 color = CalcLightByDirection(pointLight.base, lightDirection, shadowFactor);
    float attenuation = pointLight.quadIntensity * distance * distance +
                        pointLight.linearIntensity * distance +
                        pointLight.constantIntensity;

    return color / attenuation;
}

vec4 CalcPointLights()
{
    vec4 totalColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < pointLightCount; i ++)
    {
        // Ensure that the pointLight shadowMaps come before the
        // spotLight shadowMaps in the C++ code as well.
        // TODO: Make these two separate arrays so order will not matter
        totalColor += CalcPointLight(pointLights[i], i);
    }

    return totalColor;
}

vec4 CalcSpotLight(SpotLight spotLight, int shadowIndex)
{
    vec3 lightToFrag = normalize(fragPos - spotLight.base.position );
    // We want the cosine of the angle between the direction the spotLight is facing
    // and the vector from the light to the point.
    float posAngleCos = dot(lightToFrag, spotLight.direction);

    if (posAngleCos < spotLight.maxAngleCos)
    {
        return vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    vec4 color = CalcPointLight(spotLight.base, shadowIndex);

    // For soft edges on spotlights
    color = color * (posAngleCos - spotLight.maxAngleCos) / (1.0f - spotLight.maxAngleCos);

    return color;
}

vec4 CalcSpotLights()
{
    vec4 totalColor = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < spotLightCount; i ++)
    {
        // Ensure that the pointLight shadowMaps come before the
        // spotLight shadowMaps in the C++ code as well.
        // TODO: Make these two separate arrays so order will not matter
        totalColor += CalcSpotLight(spotLights[i], i + pointLightCount);
    }

    return totalColor;
}

void main()
{
    float directionalShadowFactor = CalcDirectionalShadowFactor(directionalLight);
    
    color = texture(texSampler, fragTex) * (
        CalcLightByDirection(directionalLight.base, directionalLight.direction, directionalShadowFactor) 
        + CalcPointLights()
        //+ CalcSpotLights()
    );
}
```

CalcLightByDirection works just fine. It isn't until I try to calculate point lighting that I have an issue. The omniShadowMaps array is what is causing the issue. When I try to access a simply float from the first item in the array, the fragment shader stops working. I have verified that the float in question is being set in the C++ code. The ShadowMap is harder to verify since I can see that it is being created in the C++ code, but it is being populated with data in a separate shadow cube map shader program.

There are no compile errors in the shader code because I check for them using glGetShaderInfoLog. If you want to see the full source code of my project, it can be found on [github.](https://github.com/CptMonkeyFist/Test_OpenGL)

How can I discover the cause of this error? I will admit, I do not know how to debug shader code well so it is possible that some basic openGL calls would get me the answer I need.

Comment: Does the same happen when you reduce MAX_LIGHTS to 1? There is a limit on how many textures a shader can access at the same time and you might be above that.

Comment: Wow. That was it. I never would have guessed that 16 was too many. Thank you so much. If you post it as an answer then I can upvote it.

Comment: 16 textures might work, bit MAX_LIGHTS=16 means 34 textures.

Comment: 32 textures, but yeah, I get it. The question I have now is how could I have discovered that was the problem using OpenGL calls?

Comment: Unless you were including the color texture and the directional shadow map texture. In that case, the total does reach 34.